# How to insert multiply items with entity framework and linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have an asp net web project and i try to insert multiply records to my base.
My idea is update records, and make copy of this records , with updated parameters.
But my records updates only , i don't understand how to make multiply insert ( i don't want to make foreach and insert/update by 1 record) .
*HOW CAN I MAKE UPDATE OF RECORDS AND AFTER THAT INSERT COPY OF THIS RECORDS WITH 1 CHANGED PARAMETER ?*

My code:

```
  public void SAVE(List<int> list,int stat )
        {
            var all = context.ReqForDoc.ToList();
            var friends = context.ReqForDoc.Where(f => list.Contains(f.requestN)).ToList();

            friends.ForEach(a => // UPDATE WORK
            {
                a.actual = 0;
                a.ReqStatus = stat;
                a.ChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
            });

            all.AddRange(friends); // INSERT NOW WORK

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: EF change tracker uses reference equality. Hence you have to create **new** objects with manually copying/updating properties from the original, and then add them to the corresponding `DbSet`, not to *local list* as you do currently.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry, but how can i add them to my DB, Addrange not work in this case too:   
  List<ReqInf> list2 = new List<ReqInf>();    
            list2 = context.ReqForDoc.Where(f => list.Contains(f.requestN)).ToList();    
            context.ReqForDoc.AddRange(list2);   
context.SaveChanges();

Comment: I can't tell exactly because I don't have your model, but it should be something like this (you seem to missed the **new** part of the comment) `context.ReqForDoc.AddRange(friends.Select(f => new ReqForDocType { Prop1 = f.Prop1, Prop2 = f.Prop2, ... }))`. Just don't include the PK in the select if it's identity.

Comment: @IvanStoev , i find the solution , your idea about new object was great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Thanks @ Ivan Stoev for solution. I create new object and use AddRange for insert new rows .

```
public void SAVE(List<int> list )

        {  
var all = context.ReqForDoc.ToList();
                var friends = context.ReqForDoc.Where(f => list.Contains(f.requestN)).ToList();
                friends.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    a.actual = 0;
                });

                 context.SaveChanges(); // UPDATE RECORDS

               List<ReqInf> list2 = new List<ReqInf>(); 
                list2 = context.ReqForDoc.Where(f => list.Contains(f.requestN)).ToList();
                context.ReqForDoc.AddRange(list2); //INSERT NEW
                list2.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    a.actual = 1;
                    if (a.Status == 3) { a.Status = 92; }



                });   //UPDATE INSERTED
                context.SaveChanges(); }
```